# Query to remove duplicate rows but instead displays single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following query that gave me the results of duplicate rows and that is not what I wanted

```
SELECT 
 OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
 item_description DESCRIPTION,
 item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
 FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE 
FROM OM_ITEM_MASTER, FM_PRICE_LIST 
ORDER BY item_description
```

Result:

PARTNO  DESCRIPTION MANUFACTURER    COSTPRICE
NT321   NULL    NULL    87665
NT321   NULL    NULL    2957
NT321   NULL    NULL    150
NT321   NULL    NULL    67895
NT321   NULL    NULL    5000
NT321   NULL    NULL    5000
NT321   NULL    NULL    459
NT321   NULL    NULL    459
NT321   NULL    NULL    45
NT321   NULL    NULL    45
NT321   NULL    NULL    45
NT321   NULL    NULL    45
demore          87665
demore          2957
demore          150
demore          67895
demore          5000
demore          5000
demore          459
demore          459
demore          45
demore          45
demore          45
demore          45
4565    anne    balls   87665
4565    anne    balls   2957
4565    anne    balls   150
4565    anne    balls   67895
4565    anne    balls   5000
4565    anne    balls   5000
4565    anne    balls   459
4565    anne    balls   459
4565    anne    balls   45
4565    anne    balls   45
4565    anne    balls   45
4565    anne    balls   45
345 CRUNK   WABCO   87665
345 CRUNK   WABCO   2957
345 CRUNK   WABCO   150
345 CRUNK   WABCO   67895
345 CRUNK   WABCO   5000
345 CRUNK   WABCO   5000
345 CRUNK   WABCO   459
345 CRUNK   WABCO   459
345 CRUNK   WABCO   45
345 CRUNK   WABCO   45
345 CRUNK   WABCO   45
345 CRUNK   WABCO   45
24  desktop ibm 87665
24  desktop ibm 2957
24  desktop ibm 150
24  desktop ibm 67895
24  desktop ibm 5000
24  desktop ibm 5000
24  desktop ibm 459
24  desktop ibm 459
24  desktop ibm 45
24  desktop ibm 45
24  desktop ibm 45
24  desktop ibm 45
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   87665
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   2957
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   150
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   67895
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   5000
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   5000
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   459
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   459
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   45
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   45
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   45
trtrt   fdfd    fdfdf   45
TX900   FR  NULL    87665
TX900   FR  NULL    2957
TX900   FR  NULL    150
TX900   FR  NULL    67895
TX900   FR  NULL    5000
TX900   FR  NULL    5000
TX900   FR  NULL    459
TX900   FR  NULL    459
TX900   FR  NULL    45
TX900   FR  NULL    45
TX900   FR  NULL    45
TX900   FR  NULL    45
26  gdrn    opiyo   87665
26  gdrn    opiyo   2957

1   laptop  microsoft   87665
1   laptop  microsoft   2957
1   laptop  microsoft   150
1   laptop  microsoft   67895
1   laptop  microsoft   5000
1   laptop  microsoft   5000
1   laptop  microsoft   459
1   laptop  microsoft   459
1   laptop  microsoft   45
1   laptop  microsoft   45
1   laptop  microsoft   45
1   laptop  microsoft   45
23  laptop  microsoft   87665
23  laptop  microsoft   2957
23  laptop  microsoft   150
23  laptop  microsoft   67895
23  laptop  microsoft   5000
23  laptop  microsoft   5000
23  laptop  microsoft   459
23  laptop  microsoft   459
23  laptop  microsoft   45
23  laptop  microsoft   45
23  laptop  microsoft   45
23  laptop  microsoft   45
567 originals   holly   87665
567 originals   holly   2957
567 originals   holly   150
567 originals   holly   67895
567 originals   holly   5000
567 originals   holly   5000
567 originals   holly   459
567 originals   holly   459
567 originals   holly   45
567 originals   holly   45
567 originals   holly   45
567 originals   holly   45
2   pc  ibm 87665
2   pc  ibm 2957
2   pc  ibm 150
2   pc  ibm 67895
2   pc  ibm 5000
2   pc  ibm 5000
2   pc  ibm 459
2   pc  ibm 459
2   pc  ibm 45
2   pc  ibm 45
2   pc  ibm 45
2   pc  ibm 45
123 qwe asd 87665
123 qwe asd 2957
123 qwe asd 150
123 qwe asd 67895
123 qwe asd 5000
123 qwe asd 5000
123 qwe asd 459
123 qwe asd 459
123 qwe asd 45
123 qwe asd 45
123 qwe asd 45
123 qwe asd 45
347 ROOT    MAN 87665
347 ROOT    MAN 2957
347 ROOT    MAN 150
347 ROOT    MAN 67895
347 ROOT    MAN 5000
347 ROOT    MAN 5000
347 ROOT    MAN 459
347 ROOT    MAN 459
347 ROOT    MAN 45
347 ROOT    MAN 45
347 ROOT    MAN 45
347 ROOT    MAN 45
rt56    wer dfgg    87665
rt56    wer dfgg    2957
rt56    wer dfgg    150
rt56    wer dfgg    67895
rt56    wer dfgg    5000
rt56    wer dfgg    5000
rt56    wer dfgg    459
rt56    wer dfgg    459
rt56    wer dfgg    45
rt56    wer dfgg    45
rt56    wer dfgg    45
rt56    wer dfgg    45

then i made the following changes to the query

```
SELECT distinct 
 OM_ITEM_MASTER.part_no PARTNO,
 item_description DESCRIPTION,
 item_manufacturer MANUFACTURER,
 FM_PRICE_LIST.cost_price COSTPRICE
FROM OM_ITEM_MASTER 
inner join FM_PRICE_LIST on OM_ITEM_MASTER.[PART_NO] = FM_PRICE_LIST.[PART_NO]  
order by ITEM_DESCRIPTION
```

but this displays only a single row and I want all the rows to be displayed but not duplicates. Below is the result:

PARTNO  DESCRIPTION MANUFACTURER    COSTPRICE
NT321     NULL        NULL                87665

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't see `NT321` anywhere in that data. You don't have a where clause to filter rows or any kind of grouping so it must be something wrong with the join. Change it to a left join to see if your rows come back.

Comment: thanks but the column for costprice results in null how do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you are getting a cartesian product of the two tables as you haven't defined any join condition, whereas in the second example you have defined an inner join condition which limits the result set to those items present in both tables. Maybe there are products missing in the FM_PRICE_LIST table.

Try changing the inner join to a left join to include all products from the OM_ITEM_MASTER table even if there is no corresponding row in the other table.

Also, your sample data doesn't match the queries which is a bit confusing.

Comment: HY thanks the left join made it work though it does not pull the cost price column any idea how i can go about this

Comment: thanks but the column for costprice results in null how do i go about this?

Comment: @jijicoder If the column is null it's because there are no matching values in the joined table. If you think there should be maybe you are joining on the wrong key, but I really couldn't say.

Comment: does that mean i need to create another foreign key of column cost price to match the primary key of column part_number of table om_item_master